# Get next and previous row in database table using two fields

Tags: sql

So sorry if the wording of my question is vague, but I couldn't think of how else to phrase it.
I have a table of data that includes a date field and a shift field (1, 2 or 3). Assuming a given row is currently selected, I want to be able to query this table for the previous and next record. If that's not clear enough, if the current record is date = 2018-08-13 and shift = 1, the previous record would be 2018-08-12 shift 3. I'm almost to the point of adding a field to the table that has the date and shift concatenated, but there's GOT to be a better way! (The database engine should be immaterial, but I'm using JavaDB.)

Comment: `The database engine should be immaterial` ... not at all.  If your DB doesn't support things like lead and lag, the query could be much more difficult to write.  Please edit your question and show sample data in tabular format, along with the expected output.

Comment: _Column_, not _field_.

Comment: My apologies (tough crowd!). I edited my post to use 'column' instead of 'field'. I'd been working on forms for nearly 12 hours, those aging brain cells ...
As for the engine being immaterial, all I'm looking for is the general query concept, I wasn't looking for the actual statement, though those that provided such are much appreciated! 
An amazing resource here at StackOverflow, thanks everybody.

Comment: Kind of a side comment. I actually do prefer calling the individual elements in a database record a "field", as it more accurately - and naturally - represents the data in my mind, where "column" seems to have come into use some years later with the spreadsheet and represents - again in my mind - the data for that "field" in all rows. Maybe it's just semantics, maybe this will ruffle the feathers on everyone here in StackOverflow. If so ... I won't apologize, but only say that it's unfortunate :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method.  For the previous record:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select t.* from t where t.record = ?) tt
where t.date < tt.date or
      t.date = tt.date and t.shift < tt.shift
order by t.date desc, tt.shift desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

For the next record:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select t.* from t where t.record = ?) tt
where t.date > tt.date or
      t.date = tt.date and t.shift > tt.shift
order by t.date desc, tt.shift asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that `fetch first 1 row only` retrieves one record in ANSI/ISO SQL.  Some databases use other syntax, such as `limit` or `selecct top (1)`.

Comment: Sorry I never selected the answer to my question, but this one was much more clear and straightforward (not being well-versed in SQL). Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

More info required, but one could use something like:

```
SELECT t2.* FROM [tableA] t1
INNER JOIN [tableA] t2
ON DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.DateTimeColumn, t2.DateTimeColumn) = t1.[Shift]
```

On JavaDB, I'm not sure of syntax... possibly something like:

```
SELECT t2.* FROM [tableA] t1
    INNER JOIN [tableA] t2
    ON {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_DAY, t1.DateTimeColumn, t2.DateTimeColumn)} =  t1.[Shift]
```